# realloc has triggered a Breakpoint

Tags: c

i have a problem inside my program, i've implemented a simple stack in C
the problem is that when i try to reallocate the stack array for the second time, the program triggers a brekapoint just inside the realloc function, i don't know what could be wrong since i'm using a buffer to check whether realloc fails or not. probably, this code is where i use the realloc function:

```
struct stack {
    void** data;
    int top;
    int initial_size;
};

static void stack_resize(struct stack* instance, int capacity)
{
    if (instance->initial_size == instance->top)
    {
        int new_sz = capacity * sizeof *instance->data;

        // THIS REALLOC crashes
        void** buffer = realloc(instance->data, new_sz); // realloc the stack array
        printf("reallocating memory\n");

        if (buffer) {
            instance->data = buffer;
            instance->initial_size = new_sz;
        }
    }
}
```

the following function instead, is where the **stack_resize()** gets called

```
void stack_push(struct stack* instance, void* data)
{
    if (instance->top >= instance->initial_size)
    {
        // shrink the array
        stack_resize(instance, instance->initial_size);
    }
    instance->data[++instance->top] = data;
    printf("pushing onto the stack!\n");
}
```

**This is the constructor where i initialize all the data.**

```
struct stack* stack_new(int initial_size)
{
    struct stack* new_stack = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    if (!new_stack) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no memory available from the operative system\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(new_stack, 0, sizeof(struct stack));

    new_stack->data = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * initial_size);

    if (!new_stack->data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not allocate memory for the buffer\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("created a stack with %d slot(s)\n", initial_size);

    new_stack->top = -1;
    new_stack->initial_size = initial_size;

    return new_stack;
}
```

and this is the entry point of the program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct stack* new_stack = stack_new(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++)
    {
        stack_push(new_stack, (void*)i);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! thanks to all.

Comment: is `instance->data` `NULL` at startup? how is it initialized?

Comment: What does `stack_resize(instance, instance->initial_size);` achieve exactly?

Comment: We'd need a [mcve] with a `main` program using your code

Comment: hello guys i just edited the post so you can know more about the initialization of the data.

Comment: Furthermore you seem to confuse array-size-in-elements and array-size-in-bytes. Which of the two `initial_size` is? Which of the two `new_sz` is?

Comment: Oh and why the field which clearly colds the *current capacity* named `initial_size`?

Comment: i think that the initialization of the data: `new_stack->data = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * initial_size);` where the initial size is an int, it's like if i have slots or just like int arr[10]; if in the initial_size i put 10 is the same no? and **new_sz** is the new calculated size that needs to be reallocated

Comment: When I see code with void pointers - i think something is wrong (was going to put a couple of expletives)  - Then casting `malloc`. - I have to reach for the oven glove to stop myself hurting my face

Comment: the **initial_size** should be the capacity at all, and the function `stack_resize()` takes as argument the new capacity for the array

Comment: yes the casting malloc shouldn't be there xD

`new_stack->data = malloc(sizeof(*new_stack->data) * initial_size);`

Comment: Please could you explain why you are using void pointers

Comment: Yes, i just used void pointers because i wanted to implement a generic stack

Comment: Have you considered to using C++?

Comment: We know `initial_size` is an int, it is declared as such. What does it *mean*? It's a size of something I'd guess, but in what units? US gallons? Bytes? Elements?

Comment: `initial_size` is meant to be the actual size (slots) that the stack should hold at start, for example if you put 4 as `initial_size` you meant to do like `int slots[4]`

Comment: yes i've considered using C++ but this one was a didactical exercise so i had to get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash is seen because you are assigning `new_sz` to `instance->initial_size`.
since `new_sz` holds actual size of array in bytes, which is `capacity*sizeof(void *)`

```
      int new_sz = capacity * sizeof *instance->data;

      instance->initial_size = new_sz;
```

your stack `top` and `initial_size` will mismatch.

```
if (instance->top >= instance->initial_size)
```

Your `top` will always less then `initial_size` and you will not allocate new memory.

In order to your program to work you need to make the following changes.

```
   int new_sz = (capacity+1) * sizeof(void *);

    instance->initial_size = capacity+1;//instead of new_size
```

Comment: Oh! thank you very much, it works, the program doesn't crash anymore, but i have a problem now: at the first program start when i do `stack_new(10);`
it creates a new stack with **10** slots, then it pushes 10 items, when the top is reached the `stack_resize()` gets called and it increments the capacity of 1, so i fixed it by doing: `stack_resize(capacity * 2)` so everytime it doubles the capacity 2, 4.. etc, the problem is that the first two time that the memory gets reallocated the pushed items on the stack are the same number even if the capacity is doubled..

Comment: @Lukas realloc will not alter the data inside the memory.
    it creates a new allocation, move the data there, and free the old one. so your data will not altered.

Comment: but i don't get why the stack `top` and stack `initial_size` are mismatching is they are two integers and also if the condition is evaluated as true `if (instance->top >= instance->initial_size)` <- this means the numbers are the same if it's true.. am i missing something?

Comment: Previously initial_size was holding number of bytes and top was holding number of elements.

Comment: thank you again @kiran Biradar, i will now study more and more the solution to have a clean idea!